# How to make Android pathEffect to a SVG pattern

Tags: android, svg

For example, there is a picture that a line with some short line array on it.
[image]
I know I can code it as this:

```
mPaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.MAIN_CONTOUR_LINE_YELLOW));
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
Path effectPath = new Path();
            effectPath.addRect(0,0.75f,0.21f,0.75f,
                    Path.Direction.CCW);
            mPaint.setPathEffect(
                    new PathDashPathEffect(
                            effectPath, 0.96f, 0,
                            PathDashPathEffect.Style.MORPH));

stemPaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.MAIN_CONTOUR_LINE_YELLOW));
    stemPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);//the stem line
```

so we can see we have not actually compute where every short lines located at. BUT in a particular professional graphics software, picture output as svg and here is I open it as text

```
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="1.05" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="253,412.9 
340.8,396.8 343,445.5 "/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="254" y1="412.7" x2="254.4" y2="415"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="255.9" y1="412.3" x2="256.3" y2="414.6"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="257.9" y1="412" x2="258.3" y2="414.2"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="259.8" y1="411.6" x2="260.2" y2="413.9"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="261.8" y1="411.3" x2="262.1" y2="413.5"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="263.7" y1="410.9" x2="264.1" y2="413.2"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="265.7" y1="410.5" x2="266.1" y2="412.8"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="267.6" y1="410.2" x2="268" y2="412.5"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="269.6" y1="409.8" x2="270" y2="412.1"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="271.5" y1="409.5" x2="271.9" y2="411.7"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="273.5" y1="409.1" x2="273.9" y2="411.4"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="275.4" y1="408.7" x2="275.8" y2="411"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="277.4" y1="408.4" x2="277.8" y2="410.7"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="279.3" y1="408" x2="279.7" y2="410.3"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="281.3" y1="407.7" x2="281.7" y2="409.9"/>
```

the `<line>` is more than 2 or 3 times than above actually, I delete it here.
I already know `<polyline>` is the stem line and I know `<path>` with its l,m,c char means.
So, how I make the effect path trans to svg file and the reverse?

Answer (score 0):

What you already have is about the best you can do.

You can, however, fake it somewhat by adding offset lines and applying an appropriate dash pattern.  This is not really a good general solution though.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 60">
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="1.05" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="3,22.9 
90.8,6.8 93,55.5 "/>
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="4" points="3,20.9 
90.8,4.8" stroke-dasharray="0 1 0.5 1"/>
  <polyline fill="none" stroke="#D47A00" stroke-width="4" points="92.8,5.8 95,55.5 " stroke-dasharray="0 1 0.5 1"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: it seem like that i used PathEffect didnt make any sense, i finally went to compute every short lines or dots one by one.

Comment: anyway, thanks a lot for answer me.(althought i really do not want to accept it.                                                                                                    By the way! do you know how can i establish a standard svg file format, or.ai, .eps, .tiff.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "establish a file format".

Comment: sorry, i mean output as that

Comment: Do you mean take Android Canvas calls and output them as an SVG file?  I'm not aware of anything that does that.  If you mean just build an output an SVG file, then there are any number of ways. Eg. use the XmlSerializer class or write the XML as plain text yourself.